# How does the security in the onClick tag prevent javascript injection?

Tags: javascript, html, code-injection

I've been thinking, how is the onClick tag secure (as well as other tags)? I mean, Anyone can put whatever javascript they want to execute when they trigger the onClick, what prevents someone from injecting malicious code?

[image]

Comment: what prevents someone from just running any js they want in the console? that's why you don't rely on client side security alone.

Comment: so you would have to enforce security by yourself? or the system comes with defenses against the injections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not usually whether or not a single user can run any JS in their own browser on their own computer.

The problem is when you are allowed to save that script to the database *without sanitising it first* and it then gets rendered on the page for everyone else to see and execute. Then, suddenly, they can execute code on other people's machines, steal their details, etc.

In other words, if you allow users to specify HTML markup in their comments, for example, and you don't search that markup for `<script>` tags, `onclick` attributes, etc and remove them before you save it to the database, then you have a potential problem. It becomes an actual problem when you fetch that saved markup from the DB and display it on the page somewhere without removing any JS-related functionality.

Comment: Alright, I understand now, I thought you could run javascripts that could affect the server, now I realize its clientside (why didnt I think about it first, I actually knew this)

Comment: Well, if the server just blindly accepts requests from the client, e.g. via AJAX, then you could make those requests to the server by mucking around in your JS console. If you could also request or modify data that you shouldn't have access to, then that is the problem. Always do ALL of your security checks on the server. You may do some additional ones on the client in JS, too, as a convenience, but never rely on them, they can easily be circumvented.

Answer (score 3):

The browser client is inherently insecure.  It is a completely insecure execution environment and you cannot really secure it in any way.

The way to think about this is that you do NOT control what happens in the browser.  All sorts of code can be injected, modified or run in any browser (via bookmarklets, console, direct DOM manipulation including adding arbitrary `onclick` handlers, proxy modification, debugging tools, etc...).  So, your client is inherently insecure.  Once you accept that the browser is fundamentally insecure, it's easier to understand what you need to do on your server.

That's why YOU have to validate and sanitize any results that arrive at your server from a client.  You must do this on the server in order to prevent bad data from getting into your server.  You must not trust that any data being sent to you is correct or valid.  Instead, you must validate it completely on the server before using it.

You can almost think of it like any form submission or Ajax call or a URL with query arguments or a structured URL that your server accepts is an API call to your server and you have no idea who is using that API and whether they are using it correctly or not.  Thus, you must assume nothing about the validity of the data or request as it arrives until you've checked it yourself on the server to see if everything is valid.

---

FYI, there are various techniques such as "data or function hiding in closures", code obscuration, etc... that make it more difficult for someone to mess with certain parts of your Javascript.  But, it is important to understand that these are only temporary roadblocks to the determined or skilled hacker and do not offer actual security and should not be relied upon for security.  The skilled hacker can literally replace your entire Javascript with their own modified version which pretty much means there's nothing you can do in your client-side Javascript to protect it.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely nothing prevents a client from running malicious javascript or using other developer tools. (e.g., adding form elements)

That's why it's up to **you** to keep your server-side scripts secure. (Sanitizing user input, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no protection. From the developer console/inspect element, you can modify the code in the tag. However, only you can see the modifications that you make in the inspect element, they aren't saved permanently. So other users who visit the site cannot see the code you entered inside of the developer console.

What prevents the people who *make* the page from putting malicious code into the `onclick`? Well, it's impossible to have truly dangerous code in javascript, the worst a website can do to a computer is crash the browser. So javascript is pretty safe.